# How to check in express validator if an object is not empty?

Tags: node.js, express-validator

In express-validator I would like to check that an object is not empty, i.e., if it has at least a key-value pair. However, using `notEmpty()` or `not().isEmpty()` does not work.

To be clearer let `a` be a field of a body request: if `a={}` an error should be raised, if `a={'check12': 0}` (for example) then no error should be raised.

I tried

```
check('a').exists().withMessage("MISSING").notEmpty().withMessage("EMPTY")
```

but this does not raise any `EMPTY` error if when `a={}`.

Comment: if you want to see if an object is empty one solution is `!!Object.keys({}).length`

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in a different way,

```
    const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

    app.post('/form', [
    check('name').not().isEmpty()
    ], (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty())
    {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors:"Missing Name"})
    }
   })
```